# iOS/Android: Legal way to get unique device identifier

Tags: android, ios, uniqueidentifier, iphone-privateapi, imei

We are working on **Child Anti-Abusing App** on behalf of the Slovak Republic. Currently we have an Android and iOS app available to the public thats successful in providing help and support. But we need to be more helpful for law enforcement and provide them some kind of unique identifier which could be used in cooperation with mobile network operators to track them down. Right now we are using IP address and software generated identifier. But that's not enough to track them.

**Root or Jailbreak is not a option.**

Our options:

- Legal way to solve this, is request phone number, send them code and process it automatically. This would help a great deal, but we cannot enforce kids entering phone number for various reasons.
- Another helpful identifier would be IMEI but that is not accessible on Android nor iOS.

Did we miss any option? Is it possible to get some kind of exception to do it in the background? Ideally without user interaction? Maybe contacting someone in Apple/Google (We are able address official proposal of government)? I would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: maybe this thread could help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone

Comment: This was the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48210130/1761003) which I have used in my application.

Comment: @Maveňツ We already have this, but kids doesn't use it because they are afraid of being caught. It's hard to convince them they are no longer in danger.

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but if you had adverts on your app (even just a small banner) then you might be able to use AdvertisingIdClient. I'm not entirely sure what you could do with that ID but it's at least an alternative unique identifier.

Comment: @TomasIvan in that case you may use [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient)

Answer (score 0):

There is a good way to create a token for each phone by firebase
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

This feature will not work on Huawei devices that do not have Google services, so you can create a token for Huawei phones as well:
[I can't get Firebase token from Huawei p40 series device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61623792/i-cant-get-firebase-token-from-huawei-p40-series-device)

This method will create a token for the phone, but its downside is that it is subject to change on the device, so you have to create a Firebase database and create an anonymous account on the phone automatically without the need to create a full user account “so that the process remains completely automatic.”

Comment: We know about feature but this doesn't help law enforcement to identify person nor her location. But still, we already have it implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is legal, but you can create an ID with

`getprop ril.serialnumber,ro.serialno,ro.boot.serialno`

and start it with

`https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN> /sendMessage?chat_id=<CHAT ID>&text=ID + PEDOFON`

in a Telegram channel.