# Implementing Background notification handler on flutter one signal sdk

Tags: android, ios, flutter, push-notification, onesignal

I am trying to implement the background notification handler in flutter for the one signal flutter sdk. What I am trying to do is call a method in flutter side when a background notification arrives like in the OneSignal docs suggests https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/service-extensions#android-notification-extender-service .
This is my MainActrivity.kt

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import com.onesignal.OneSignal.OSRemoteNotificationReceivedHandler;

var channel: MethodChannel? = null

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.dev/notification";
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine){
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
        channel = MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL);
    }
}

public class NotificationServiceExtension : OSRemoteNotificationReceivedHandler{
    override fun remoteNotificationReceived(Context context, OSNotificationReceivedEvent notificationReceivedEvent) {
       channel.invokeMethod("testNotification");
    }
}
```

I have never written Kotlin code before and maybe I am doing something wrong here as this is resulting in build errors. Has anyone here done something similar before? Would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

```
onesignal_flutter: 3.2.8
flutter doctor :
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.1, on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 5.13.0-30-generic,
    locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] VS Code
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

Comment: For this reason I don't use OneSignal, you can see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71331313/2877427